# Compile XPC service with a different architecture than the client

Tags: swift, xpc

I'm working on a macOS application that deals with a few external dependencies that can only be compiled for intel (`x86_64`) but I want the app to run natively on both `arm` and `x86_64`.

One idea I have been playing with is to move the `x86_64` dependencies to an xpc service compiled only as `x86_64` and use the service only the intel machine. However, I can't figure out how to setup my project to compile everything at once...

Any ideas? Is this even possible? If not, I'm open to suggestions...

Thanks